# Cordova/Phonegap: What is the difference between the below 2 file paths?

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, cordova

In `Phonegap`,  I use `<input type='file' id='fileType' />` to select the files. It opens the file selector window.

However once the device's file selector window is open, from the left side nav bar (android) there are 2 ways you an get the file; one is my directly selecting something like "Audio", "Videos" etc and get a file; The other one is selecting `File Manager` and get a file.

If I chose file manager to get the file, the file path is something like - `file:///storage/emulated/0/testwave.wav`

If I select it from `Audio` or something similar, then the file path is something like - `content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/audio%3A5821`

What's the difference between these 2 paths? I also noticed that the second path gives a file where you can send via `REST` API (Ajax) as well, while you can't do the same with the frst type of path.

Comment: not sure why this happens but the problem arises for the 2 nd type uri that content uri... for that reason you can use https://github.com/hiddentao/cordova-plugin-filepath... but you can send via ajax using file uri always...

Comment: @Banik: I don't need the original path, I need the URI.